# why does't explode function work in laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

It is working in the editor and gives a expected output.
But when running the project, it would not get expected output.

**code:**

```
@php 
$pro ="cat-19,subcat-52,subcat-55";
$var=explode(",",$pro);
@endphp
@foreach($var as $row)
  {{$row}}
@endforeach
```

**What could be the problem in my code?**

Comment: output::cat-19 subcat-52 subcat-55                                                                             
 Expected output:Array ( [0] => cat-19 [1] => subcat-52 [2] => subcat-55 )

Comment: Welcome to SO .. what you want to achive your code seem correct

Comment: if i use ,(coma) in explode, coma will be gone. if i use -(hyfen) in explode, hyfen will be gone. what's the problem in project i don't understand

Comment: so you want the `print_r($var)` output?

Comment: i need this output ```Array ( [0] => cat-19 [1] => subcat-52 [2] => subcat-55 )```.but i can't find this in my project.any suggestion for that??

Comment: I think you want to `print_r($var)` and not `{{$row}}` inside the loop.If you  `print_r($var)` you will get an associative array like `Array ( [0] => cat-19 [1] => subcat-52 [2] => subcat-55 )` while `{{$row}}` gives only the values inside the array.

Comment: i got your point bro.thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to have a preview of the array.

```
$pro ="cat-19,subcat-52,subcat-55";
$var=explode(",",$pro);

print_r($var); 
/* this will give you an associative array
result from print_r will be Array ( [0] => cat-19 [1] => subcat-52 [2] => subcat-55 ) */

@endphp
@foreach($var as $row)
  {{$row}}
@endforeach 

/* inside the loop since you are printing the value you will get the output as,
cat-19 subcat-52 subcat-55 */
```

Comment: @paribibidotcom accepting the answer would be highly appreciated!!